# Get Day of the month

Tags: java, calendar

I understand that java.time package introduced in Java 8 is much simpler to use. However, I am doing a challenge in Java 7 and when I run my code and I am breaking my head as to what the mistake is. I am trying to print Day of the week (in text) on last line. However, it prints null in the last print. If I change the month from 7 to 8, it prints Saturday in the last print statement. Wondering, what I am doing wrong.

### Output with month parameter for new GregorianCalendar as 7

Wed Aug 05 00:00:00 AEST 2015

4

null

### Output with month parameter for new GregorianCalendar as 8

Sat Sep 05 00:00:00 AEST 2015

7

Saturday

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Calendar calendar  = new GregorianCalendar(2015,7,5);
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime().toString());

        System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));


        System.out.println(calendar.getDisplayName(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK),Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault()));


    }
}
```

Comment: Does this time happen to be at a daylight savings time change?

Comment: try `calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, ...)` instead of `calendar.getDisplayName(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK), ...)`

Comment: Andy Turner - My system time is Sydney. So Daylight savings time at the moment. not sure if that is what you are after.

Comment: Jesper - Thanks this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you should not use `GregorianCalendar` in 2019. Not in Java 7 either. java.time, the modern Java date and time API, has been backported. Use ThreeTen Backport. See the links at the bottom.

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.AUGUST, 5);
    DayOfWeek dow = date.getDayOfWeek();
    System.out.println(dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH));
```

Output is:

> Mon

### What went wrong in your code?

You had wanted:

```
    System.out.println(calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault()));
```

The first argument to `getDisplayName` is a field code like `DAY_OF_WEEK`. When instead passing *the actual value* of that field, you risk giving it an invalid value, in which case the method returns `null` (which may be confusing — thanks to Kevin Andersson for acknowledging this as Understatement of the year (;->)!).

Field 4 is `WEEK_OF_MONTH`. The weeks of the month haven’t got names, only numbers, which is why no string representation is applicable for this field. Field 7 is `DAY_OF_WEEK`, so that you got the expected result in the second case (8 = September) was a mere coincidence.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: "_...**may** be confusing_"?  Understatement of the year (;->)!

Comment: Thanks to Ole V.V. for the detailed information. I can't use any other external jars as it is an online editor where I can't import. But I have made the change for the first parameter of Calendar.getDisplayName() as suggested and it worked.